# XMLHttpRequest with php returns the script when using Phonegap cordova

Tags: php, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am trying to build a mobile application using cordova. I needed a qr-scanner so I added the phonegap barcode scanner for this purpose:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

The script i am trying to run is the following:

```
<script>
    function scan() {  
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {
                        var xmlhttp;
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                cadeaubon = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                                }
                        }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/getCadeaubon.php?id=" + result.text, true);

                        xmlhttp.send();
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            },
            {
                preferFrontCamera : false, // iOS and Android
                showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
                showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
                torchOn: false, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
                saveHistory: true, // Android, save scan history (default false)
                prompt : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android
                resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500
                formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
                orientation : "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
                disableAnimations : true, // iOS
                disableSuccessBeep: false // iOS and Android
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

The php script that runs with this XMLHttpRequest is the following:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "AHR1822";
$db = "lekker_lokaal";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$result = $conn->query("
    SELECT cadeaubonID, handelaarsID, genBonLocatie, waarde, ontvanger, koper, aankoopdatum, status
    FROM cadeaubons
    WHERE cadeaubonID ='".$id."'
");
$outp = array();
$outp = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

But when I run the android or browser build of this project, instead of runne-ing the php code, it just returns the file.
This worked fine when I used this same method in a normal web application.

Can someone help me, because I am out of ideas right now.

Comment: Did you check you server configuration?

Comment: I realised I had been using a wamp server on this script when I ran it for my normal web application, so I created a database on Infinity Free. When I tried to connect to that online database, everything works fine but on cordova the XMLHttpRequest still returns the contents of the php file, so that wasn't the problem at least

Comment: Also, I don't think the server/database is really the issue, the php file is stored locally and even if don't include any connection to a db, the problem still persists...

Comment: Oh, I think the problem lies with cordova. According to this question, cordova cannot interpret php files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636828/how-to-run-php-code-inside-cordova?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
I will try to host them on a FTP server and try that way

Comment: Ok, so I posted the php script files on 000WebHost and called them in my javascript, seems to work fine now. Just have to add the cordova whitelist plugin for android.